# codeigniter: passing variable to controller which loads a form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a link which when clicked passes an argument to my controller to a function like so:

/home/inquire/54

- I want to then load a view which has a form in it and gather some input data.
- I then want to email both the argument and the form data to myself

This is my controller:

```
public function inquire($id) {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputName', 'Name', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('client/M_inquire.php');
    } else {

        $this->email->from('noreply@test.com', 'System');
        $this->email->to('contactus@test.com');
        $this->email->subject('New Client Registration');

        $this->email->message(
                "Name: " . $this->input->post('inputName') . "<br />" .
                "Phone: " . $this->input->post('inputPhone') . "<br />" .
                "Email: " . $this->input->post('inputEmail') . "<br />" .
                "Nurse profession: " . $this->input->post('inputProfession') . "<br />" .
                "Nurse ID: " . $nurseid
        );
        $this->email->send();
        $this->load->view('client/M_inquire_success.php');
    }
}
```

THis is my view:

```
    <?php echo form_open('home/inquire'); ?>
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" name= "inputName" id="inputName">
```

The problem is the controller expects an argument so when the form opens it crashes. Any idea how I can maintain the first argument I passed and gather some form data and email both?

THanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to `form_open` in your view you can append the `id`.

So, in your controller you could have something like:

```
...
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $data['the_id'] = $id;
    $this->load->view('client/M_inquire.php', $data);
} else {
...
```

and then in the view you have:

```
<?php echo form_open('home/inquire/' . $the_id); ?>
```

Comment: Brilliant. So simple, I'm not sure how I missed it. Thanks so much!